vba code to import excel table short date field to sharepoint date time field where time is not required
Option Explicit

    SharePoint Connection
        Public Const vURL As String = "https://mysharepoint.com/site/"
        'obtain list from Settings URL List=1use-list-4id4-for9-b1sharepoint8list
        Public Const vGUID As String = "{1use-list-4id4-for9-b1sharepoint8list}"   '<-- SPList
        Public vConn As Object 'Needs ActiveX Data Objects 2.8
        Public vConnString As String 'Needs ActiveX Data Objects 2.8
        Public vRS As Recordset 'Needs ActiveX Data Objects 2.8
        Public vSQL As String
        Public vCmd As ADODB.Command
    
        Public vWB As Workbook
        Public vWS As Worksheet
        Public tbl As ListObject
        Public i As Integer
        Public requestDate As String
        Public lastrow As Double
        Sub ImportToSP()
        Set vWB = ActiveWorkbook
        Set vWS = vWB.Sheets("RenewalForm")
        Set tbl = vWS.ListObjects("Renewal")
        
        Sub ImportToSP()
        Set vWB = ActiveWorkbook
        Set vWS = vWB.Sheets("RenewalForm")
        Set tbl = vWS.ListObjects("Renewal")
        
        'Delete blank rows in table
        lastrow = vWS.Range("Renewal").Rows.Count + 1
        
        For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        Next i
        
        'Open Connection
        vConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=" & vURL & ";LIST=" & vGUID & ";"
        'VIEW=" & spVIEW & ";"
        
         'Create and open the connection
        Set vConn = New ADODB.Connection
        vConn.ConnectionString = vConnString
        vConn.Open
        
         'Loop through each row in the table, skipping the header row
        For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
            ' Get the values for each column
            With tbl.ListRows(i).Range
            ' Format the date field to match SharePoint's expected format
                requestDate = Format(.Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("ReqDATE").Index).Value, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ss")
    
                vSQL = "INSERT INTO [RegistrationIMPORT] (" & _
                        "[Request Type], " & _
                        "[Group], " & _
                        "[Requester], " & _
                        "[ReqDATE], " & _
                        "[Unit], " & _
                        "[Full VIN], " & _
                        "[State], " & _
                        "[Plate Number], " & _
                        "[Vehicle needs sticker], " & _
                        "[Vehicle needs plate], " & _
                        "[Comments]) " & _
                        "VALUES (" & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("RequestType").Index).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("Group").Index).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, requestDate).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("Requester").Index).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("Unit").Index).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("Full VIN").Index).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("State").Index).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("Plate Number").Index).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("Vehicle needs sticker").Index).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("Vehicle needs plate").Index).Value & "', " & _
                        "'" & .Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("Comments").Index).Value & "')"
    
                ' Execute the SQL command
                On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
                vConn.Execute vSQL
            End With
        Next i
    
        ' Close and clean up the connection
        If vConn.State = adStateOpen Then
            MsgBox "Thank you for submitting the Registration Request!  Duplicate MSO turnaround time of 7-10      
             business days; except for Nissan requests, please allow 4-6 weeks to complete."
            vConn.Close
            'Clear range if add happened
            Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(tbl.ListRows.Count + 1, 10)).ClearContents
            ' Save the active workbook
            'vWB.Save
        End If
        Set vConn = Nothing
    
        Exit Sub
    
        ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox "Request was not submitted.  Please make sure all fields have data and resubmit." &      
        Err.Description
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        If vConn.State = adStateOpen Then vConn.Close
        Set vConn = Nothing
        End Sub

Error Date type mismatch in criteria expression on the two lines below:
line of code......"'" & .Cells(1, requestDate).Value & "', " & _
If I remove these two lines of code, it works just fine.  I have the date in excel table as short date, in SharePoint as Date Time but the time is not required.  I also have a formula in the excel table that will auto enter today's date =TODAY() in the date field.
I received the below from Microsoft...but I'm still lost...I've tried many different syntax types of the line of code above:

The requestDate variable is formatted to match the ISO 8601 date
format (yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ss), which is commonly used by SharePoint for
date and time fields. This should help resolve the data type mismatch
error you're encountering.

With tbl.ListRows(i).Range
Format the date field to match SharePoint's expected format

requestDate = Format(.Cells(1, tbl.ListColumns("ReqDATE").Index).Value, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ss")



End With

Any assistance with the syntax would be of great help.

I guess, instead of .Cells(1, requestDate).Value you need to write just requestDate because it is calculated at the beginning of the For-Next loop

You also have the values for [Requester] and [ReqDATE] in the wrong order...

Yes the values for Requester and ReqDate are not in order, but it works none the less -- without the ReqDate that is.  I have tried the "'" & requestDate & "', " & _   along with many, many other syntax options.  It still gives me errors.    Any other suggestions?  MS says this user group is my best option.  I can't believe this is this difficult.  MS created SharePoint, you'd think they'd know how to import via code.  Anyway, all suggestions are welcome.  Thanks.
